# Using the upcoming C++ reflection facilities to print the full name of a type

Tags: c++, templates, reflection

Currently, one can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to display a template type under `gcc`, and `clang`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print_type() {
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  print_type<const volatile int&>();
  return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
void print_type() [with T = const volatile int&]
```

With the [reflection TS](https://cplusplus.github.io/reflection-ts/draft.pdf) coming and reflection facilities in C++, I was wondering what the syntax would look like to be able to do something similar.

Note: as the reflection TS has not been voted in yet, I am only looking for a "probable" syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing something like this:

```
template <class T>
void print_type() {
    using F = reflexpr(print_type<T>);
    std::cout << get_display_name_v<F> << std::endl;
}
```

You have to `reflexpr` a specific thing, there's no way to get "this function I find myself in" - so that's `print_type<T>`. And then the documentation just says that this is implementation defined.

If you want to write it all out, you can do:

```
template <class T>
void print_type() {
    std::cout << "void "
              << get_name_v<reflexpr(print_type<T>)> // guaranteed "print_type"
              << "() [with T = "
              << get_display_name_v<reflexpr(T)> 
              << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

It's unclear to me what `get_name_v<reflexpr(const volatile int&)>` actually is. It seems like it's probably empty - `T` is not a *simple-type-specifier* in this case) and there is no mention of cv- or ref-qualifiers, which is why I used `get_display_name_v`.

---

Note that the Reflection TS is type-based - each `reflexpr` gives you a type that you have to do type-based metaprogramming in. The approach the language itself will likely end up with is *value*-based reflection - that is `reflexpr` yields a value of a small set of predefined reflection object types. This will make it easier to actually code, and is why we papers like `constexpr!` and support for `constexpr` allocation in the works.