# How to get a variable name from pointer

Tags: c++

I need to make some kind of inspector, and i was wondering if it was possible to make something like that

```
#include <iostream>

#define GET_VARIABLE_NAME(name) (#name)

int main()
{
    int some_variable = 0;
    int* some_pointer = &some_variable;

    cout << GET_VARIABLE_NAME(*some_pointer) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And to get "some_variable" as result.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you do your own explicit mapping from pointer to name you can't. C++ doesn't have this kind of [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection). And why do you want it? What is the problem you're trying to solve with it?

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I'm working on a little game engine and I wanted to try some different ways to make a kind of inspector for the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to do that.

If you write

```
int some_variable = 0;
int* some_pointer = &some_variable;
```

Then `some_pointer` holds the memory adress of `some_variable`. Other than that there is no relation between the two. Also what would you expect to get if you write

```
int some_variable = 0;
int** some_pointer_pointer = & ( &some_variable);

cout << GET_VARIABLE_NAME(*some_pointer_pointer) << endl;
```

There exists no variable that holds the value of `*some_pointer_pointer`.

If you want to map pointers to names, you can do it manually, with eg a `std::map<int*,std::string>`. Though, I doubt that this will help you, because pointers can be reassigned to point elsewhere and you would need to update the map.

Answer (score 1):

What you are taking about is called [Run-time Type Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461379/using-the-upcoming-c-reflection-facilities-to-print-the-full-name-of-a-type), and it's a feature that has been discussed being added to C++ for decades, but as of yet, hasn't been.

If you need this, you need to either wait for the standards committee, roll your own, or use a library to add the functionalty you need.

https://www.rttr.org/

Comment: OP wants to get the name of the variable, not the name of the type